# Aws Lambda Asynchronous JavaScript Calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, aws-lambda

I am using below code for resizing multiple images:

Sample request1 :/images/0/products/1/10x10$20x20$30x30/test.jpg

Sample request 2:/images/0/banners/10x10$20x20$30x30/test.jpg

Here, I am trying to process image resize for two types of images. One of product and one of banners.Sample json I am using for request:

```
            {
          "Records": [
        {
          "cf": {
        "config": {
          "distributionDomainName": "d30ctzvvm0c9tj.cloudfront.net",
          "distributionId": "E7L07HTI8617C",
          "eventType": "origin-response"
        },
        "request": {
          "clientIp": "103.217.247.2",
          "headers": {
        "user-agent": [
          {
            "key": "User-Agent",
            "value": "Amazon CloudFront"
          }
        ],
        "via": [
          {
            "key": "Via",
            "value": "1.1 126c88e8d3434fec67dab0faaa786e61.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
          }
        ],
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": [
          {
            "key": "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests",
            "value": "1"
          }
        ],
        "accept-encoding": [
          {
            "key": "Accept-Encoding",
            "value": "gzip"
          }
        ],
        "x-forwarded-for": [
          {
            "key": "X-Forwarded-For",
            "value": "103.217.247.2"
          }
        ],
        "host": [
          {
            "key": "Host",
            "value": "test-cloudfront-shirsh.s3.amazonaws.com"
              }
            ]
          },
          "method": "GET",
          "origin": {
        "s3": {
          "authMethod": "origin-access-identity",
          "customHeaders": {},
          "domainName": "test-cloudfront-shirsh.s3.amazonaws.com",
          "path": "",
          "region": "ap-south-1"
            }
          },
          "querystring": "d=10x10$20x20$30x30",
          "uri": "/images/0/banners/10x10$20x20$30x30/test.jpg"
        },
        "response": {
          "headers": {
        "x-amz-request-id": [
          {
            "key": "x-amz-request-id",
            "value": "1B822F690E9022FF"
          }
        ],
        "x-amz-id-2": [
          {
            "key": "x-amz-id-2",
            "value": "rfK2MUwZnmBmp5KssOJfKK+hTLNwHiNrxFAwqbWRE2yXt8PQzEWNgJmhVSh488Me7wXupuu8w8A="
          }
        ],
        "date": [
          {
            "key": "Date",
            "value": "Fri, 12 Oct 2018 10:04:55 GMT"
          }
        ],
        "server": [
          {
            "key": "Server",
            "value": "AmazonS3"
          }
        ],
        "content-type": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/xml"
          }
        ],
        "transfer-encoding": [
          {
            "key": "Transfer-Encoding",
            "value": "chunked"
              }
            ]
          },
          "status": "404",
          "statusDescription": "Forbidden"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

For above request(Banner):

Source Image Bucket: /images/0/banners/test.jpg

Sizes to be geneated: 10x10, 20x20 ,30x30

Dest Image Bucket:

```
  /images/0/banners/10x10/test.jpg
  /images/0/banners/20x20/test.jpg
  /images/0/banners/30x30/test.jpg
```

However, it is saving only for last image :  /images/0/banners/30x30/test.jpg

My Js code:

```
              'use strict';

          const http = require('http');
          const https = require('https');
          const querystring = require('querystring');

          const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
          const S3 = new AWS.S3({
            signatureVersion: 'v4',
          });
          const Sharp = require('sharp');

          // set the S3 and API GW endpoints
          const BUCKET = 'test-cloudfront-shirsh';

          exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
            let response = event.Records[0].cf.response;

            console.log("Response Header::" + JSON.stringify(response));
        console.log("Response status code :%s", response.status);

        const variables = {
              allowedDimension : [],

        };


        // check if image is not present
        if (response.status == 404 || response.status == 403) {

          let request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
          let params = querystring.parse(request.querystring);

          console.log("d=" + params.d);
          // if there is no dimension attribute, just pass the response
          if (!params.d) {
            callback(null, response);
            return;
          }


          variables.allowedDimension=params.d.split("$");  


          if(variables.allowedDimension.length >=1 ){


          var prod_regex=/\/images\/0\/products\/(\d+)/;
          var banner_regex=/\/images\/0\/banners/;
          let path,prefix, originalKey, match, width, height, requiredFormat, imageName,bucketKey,key,dimArray,dimensionRatios;
        console.log("Using forEach");
              variables.allowedDimension.forEach(function(dimension, index){


                 path = request.uri;

                dimensionRatios= path.split('/');
        console.log("Path::" + path);
          try {
            // "/images/0/banners/20x20/jpg/abc.jpg";
         if(banner_regex.test(path)){

          console.log("Regex for banner");
          key = path.replace(dimensionRatios[4],dimension);
           dimArray = dimension.split("x");
           match = key.match(/\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(\d+)x(\d+)\/(.*)/);
           prefix = match[1]+"/"+match[2]+"/"+match[3]+ "/";
            imageName = match[6];

        }if(prod_regex.test(path)){

          console.log("Regex for product");
          key = path.replace(dimensionRatios[5],dimension);
          dimArray = dimension.split("x");
          match=key.match(/\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)x(\d+)\/(.*)/);
          prefix = match[1]+"/"+match[2]+"/"+match[3]+ "/" + match[4] + "/";
          imageName = match[7];

        }
        width = parseInt(dimArray[0],10);
        height = parseInt(dimArray[1],10); 
        requiredFormat = "jpg";
        originalKey = prefix + imageName; 

        bucketKey= prefix + dimension + "/" + imageName;

            console.log("dimension::" + dimension + "\nkey::"+ key +"\npath::"+path +"\nPrefx:::" + prefix + "\nimageName:" +imageName
          + "\nWidthxHeight" + width + "x" + height + "\nBucket Key:" + bucketKey+"\nOrig Key::" + originalKey);

          }
          catch (err) {

            console.log("no prefix present.."+err);

          }

          // get the source image file
          S3.getObject({ Bucket: BUCKET, Key: originalKey }).promise()
            // perform the resize operation
        .then(data => Sharp(data.Body)
          .resize(width, height)
          .ignoreAspectRatio()
          .toFormat(requiredFormat)
          .toBuffer()
        )
        .then(buffer => {

          console.log("Putting image for buckt key :" + bucketKey );
          // save the resized object to S3 bucket with appropriate object
        // key.
          S3.putObject({
              Body: buffer,
              Bucket: BUCKET,
              ContentType: 'image/' + requiredFormat,
          CacheControl: 'max-age=31536000',
          Key: bucketKey,
          StorageClass: 'STANDARD'
          }).promise()
          // even if there is exception in saving the object we send back
        // the generated
          // image back to viewer below
          .catch(error => { console.log("Exception while writing resized image to bucket",error)});


         response.status = 200;
         response.body = buffer.toString('base64');
          response.bodyEncoding = 'base64';
          response.headers['content-type'] = [{ key: 'Content-Type', value: 'image/' + requiredFormat }];
             callback(null, response);
            })
          .catch( err => {
            console.log("Exception while reading source image with error :",err);
          });

           // generate a binary response with resized image

          });
          // read the S3 key from the path variable.
          // Ex: path variable /images/100x100/webp/image.jpg


          }else{
            callback(null, response);
          }

          // read the required path. Ex: uri /images/100x100/webp/image.jpg


        } // end of if block checking response statusCode
        else {
          // allow the response to pass through
              callback(null, response);
            }
          };
```

Comment: Hey, welcome, please consider reducing your example to an [mcve] it's pretty hard to grok what you're asking here so it's hard to give you an answer :)

Comment: formatting ... makes code easy to read

Comment: see this line `let path, prefix, originalKey, match, width, height, requiredFormat, imageName, bucketKey, key, dimArray, dimensionRatios;` ... put that **INSIDE** the `variables.allowedDimension.forEach(function(dimension, index) {` loop - that will most likely fix your issue

Comment: Though, does `callback` expect to be called multiple times (i.e. once for each forEach)

Comment: Thanks all..what I was missing was closure..Implemented the same,Problem solved